# Format HTML/Text email content to include vertical lines in replies and previous emails

Tags: php, python, html, django, email

I'm building email functionality into an application.  Most all email clients mark previous messages in the reply text with a vertical line (perhaps just the "|" character?) along the entire left hand side of the message.

Does anyone know a function/utility (preferably in python), however I can adopt from anything) that would format HTML and text content in this way? It sounds like a pretty easy problem but it's actually quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

For plain text you can use the [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module. Just specify `'| '` as the `initial_indent` and `subsequent_indent` arguments.

Doing it with HTML requires a different approach, since HTML is normally formatted by the browser. I guess it should be possible using CSS, but I've never done it myself, so I don't know the details.